# Evaluate the following series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big(e^{(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}}+2+e^{-(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}}\big)^{-1} $

Tags: calculus, summation

I found this convergent series while solving a calculus problem  $$  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \big(e^{(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}}+2+e^{-(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}}\big)^{-1}=A $$How can I evaluate A?

### My Attempt

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \big(e^{(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}}+2+e^{-(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}}\big)^{-1}=0.00429610616+1.5281084 \times 10^{-12}+5.3886194 \times 10^{-22}+...$$
The summation appears to converge at around 0.004308 using excel but how can I evaluate this sum analytically?

Comment: Which calculus problem ? This may (or may not) be of some help. Also, this rewrites itself as : $$A=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{cosh}[(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}]}.$$

Comment: Or also $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh((4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}/2)}\right)^2$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D++%5Cbig%28e%5E%7B%284n%2B1%29%5Cpi%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%2B2%2Be%5E%7B-%284n%2B1%29%5Cpi%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%5Cbig%29%5E%7B-1%7D) expresses the answer using a generalized polygamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+\text{cosh}[(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}]}$$ As mentioned in comments, a CAS gives
$$S_p=\frac{\psi _{e^{4 \sqrt{3} \pi }}^{(1)}\left(p-\frac{i}{4
   \sqrt{3}}+\frac{5}{4}\right)-\psi _{e^{4 \sqrt{3} \pi }}^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{12}
   \left(3-i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)}{48 \pi ^2}$$ where appear the q-polygamma function.

If $p\to \infty$
$$\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3} \pi }-\frac{\psi _{e^{4 \sqrt{3} \pi }}^{(1)}\left(-\frac{i \pi
   -\sqrt{3} \pi }{4 \sqrt{3} \pi }\right)}{48 \pi ^2}\approx 0.00429610616779$$

As you noticed, the convergence is very fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 0 &\color{red}{ 0.00429610616}62624620267200340161868494728474773150101 \\
 1 &\color{red}{ 0.0042961061677905704599958358}661023829062918667327659 \\
 2 &\color{red}{ 0.0042961061677905704605346978063372}090930922497948456 \\
 3 &\color{red}{ 0.0042961061677905704605346978065272297646}032916399424 \\
 4 &\color{red}{ 0.0042961061677905704605346978065272297646702992589}733 \\
 5 &\color{red}{ 0.0042961061677905704605346978065272297646702992589970}
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is normal since
$$a_n=\frac{1}{1+\text{cosh}[(4n+1)\pi\sqrt{3}]} \sim e^{-\sqrt{3} \pi  (4 n+1)}$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \sim e^{-4 \sqrt{3} \pi }\approx 3.53 \times 10^{-10}$$